# Purpose of "pandas metadata" in Parquet file

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

If you write a pandas DataFrame to parquet file (using the `.to_parquet(..)` method), it will produce a bunch of metadata in the parquet footer. This is [documented on the pandas site](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.4/development/developer.html). The metadata includes things like index names and ranges, column names and datatypes, etc.

My question is - why is this useful for pandas? The column name and datatype information is already in the parquet schema.

I'm putting some business/domain specific metadata into the parquet file, and I suppose the "real question" is whether I should retain pandas metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the doc:

> So that a pandas.DataFrame can be faithfully reconstructed, we store a pandas metadata key in the FileMetaData

There are some pandas concepts that parquet doesn't support out of the box. For example index or categorical dtype.

Take this table for example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.Series([1, 2], name='id'),
        pd.Series(['a', 'b'], name='value')
    ],
    axis=1
).set_index('id')
```

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |

If you save it to parquet and load it back:

```py
df.to_parquet("hello.parquet")

table = pq.read_table('hello.parquet')

table_as_df = table.to_pandas()
```

You get the same dataframe back:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |

And you can check with:

```py
pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(table_as_df, df)
```

But if you strip the metadata:

```
table_as_df_no_metadata = table.replace_schema_metadata({}).to_pandas()
```

The index becomes a normal column:
|    | value   |   id |
|---:|:--------|-----:|
|  0 | a       |    1 |
|  1 | b       |    2 |

And the dataframes are not the same anymore:

```py
pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(table_as_df_no_metadata, df)
```

Throws:

```
AssertionError: DataFrame are different

DataFrame shape mismatch
[left]:  (2, 2)
[right]: (2, 1)
```

> the "real question" is whether I should retain pandas metadata.

The answer is it depends. If you are using concepts that map one to one from parquet to pandas (eg: don't use index), then you should be fine stripping the pandas metadata, but if not you may have some bad surprises.